# Custom admin edit page for single custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I have a custom role "department admin", and custom post type "department page". Each department admin linked to a department. I need a custom page in admin to edit linked department page. I also used ACF plugin in department page for some custom field, any solution for this problem?

Comment: Simplest solution will be to use a plugin user role editor and create a new role for every department and assign respectively. Alternative less easier solution will be to register another admin menu, add user meta with department name for each department head and on the new page show department post based on the user meta.

Comment: The long winded solution is to determine the hook controlling the output of post.php, assign department identifying user meta to each department head, check of different user roles(admin, department head and any other) and based on role check the user meta and show posts respectively. First is easiest and second is also feasible but little more time consuming and third may take a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i made solution, Menu replaced with `admin_menu` action hook which means all listing menu replaced to edit post menu with associated id and removed add new page menu. Also add a redirection in `admin_init` action hook. All above action hooks will apply based on user role.